# what are alternatives to throwing exceptions in objective c

Tags: objective-c

Google Coding Standard for Objective C says we should [not throw exceptions](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml#Avoid_Throwing_Exceptions), what are the alternatives to `@throw` then?

Comment: The Google coding standards do not say **we** should not throw exceptions.  They only say that people writing code for Google open source projects should not use exceptions.

Comment: you are right, it's just that I try to follow their guidelines in my projects too. you never know when you might mixing C++ with it and it will cause problems for objects created on stack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility is to deliver extended exception information via [`NSError`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
- (BOOL) doSomethingWhichCanFailWithError: (NSError**)aLocation {
    ...
    if( didFail ) {

        if( aLocation ) {

            *aLocation = [NSError errorWithDomain: kMyErrorDomain code: myErrorCode userInfo: nil];
        }
    }

    return !didFail;
}
```

The caller can test if the call succeeded by inspecting the result value. If more information is required in case of an error, it can supply a location, where the method can store additional information into:

```
NSError* error = nil;

if( ![instance doSomethingWhichCanFailWithError: &error] ) {

    NSString* domain = [error domain];

    if( [kMyErrorDomain isEqual: domain] ) {

         switch( [error code] ) {
         case ...: ...
         default: ...
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 This is the Apple recommended pattern.  Personally I like exceptions  and I use them where appropriate but you can't allow exceptions to propagate outside your own code because whatever calls your code may not support exceptions.

Comment: Is there a recommended pattern also which deals with asynchronous errors? i.e. network error codes etc. that isn't detectable beforehand?